# XML validate against DTD in java

Tags: java, dtd

In my java springboot application i am trying to validate xml against dtd, getting below exception though given xml is valid as per dtd definition, not sure what i am missing here. Could someone help me?

**Java Code:**
This method takes 2 parameters one xml message and another one dtd details

```
public class XMLValidator {
  public boolean validate(String xmlMsg, String dtdFileName){
    boolean flag = false;
    try(InputStream dtdFileStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(dtdFileName);
        InputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMsg.getBytes());
        SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(dtdFileStream, xmlStream)){
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        saxParserFactory.setValidating(true);
        SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        saxParser.parse(is, new MyHandler());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Validate==>"+ e);
    }
    return flag;
 }

static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
   @SpringBootTest
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {XMLValidator.class})
   public class ValidatorTest {
    @Autowired
    XMLValidator xmlValidator;
    @Test
    public void testValidate() throws Exception{
        String xmlMsg = getXml("sam.xml");
        String dtdFileName = "sample.dtd";
        xmlValidator.validate(xmlMsg, dtdFileName);
    }
  public String getXml(String filePath) throws Exception{
    String xml = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath),"UTF-8");
    return xml;
  }
 }
```

**DTD:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!ELEMENT CMSERVICESMSG (GBLMSGHDR, SIGNONMSGSRQV1, PRESDOCMSGREQ)>
 <!ELEMENT GBLMSGHDR (HDRINFO, MSGATTRIB)>
 <!ELEMENT HDRINFO (HDRVERSNBRID)>
 <!ELEMENT HDRVERSNBRID (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT MSGATTRIB (MSGID, MSGREQ, MSGTYPE, RESPREQIND)>
 <!ELEMENT MSGID (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT MSGREQ (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT MSGTYPE (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT RESPREQIND (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT SIGNONMSGSRQV1 (AUTHENTICATION?)?>
 <!ELEMENT AUTHENTICATION (USERID?, USERPASS?)?>
 <!ELEMENT USERID (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT USERPASS (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT PRESDOCMSGREQ (ARCHIVEITEM, FUNCTION, SEARCHINFO?, AUDITINFO?, DOCINFO*)>
 <!ELEMENT ARCHIVEITEM (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT FUNCTION (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT SEARCHINFO (MAXRECNBR?)?>
 <!ELEMENT MAXRECNBR (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT AUDITINFO (TOTDOCNBR?)?>
 <!ELEMENT TOTDOCNBR (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT DOCINFO (GBLMETAINFO?)?>
 <!ELEMENT GBLMETAINFO (ATTRIBUTE*, CHILDCOMPONENT*, DOCMETAINFO)?>
 <!ELEMENT CHILDCOMPONENT (ATTRIBUTE*)>
 <!ATTLIST CHILDCOMPONENT ID CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST CHILDCOMPONENT IGNORE (TRUE|FALSE) "FALSE">
 <!ELEMENT DOCMETAINFO (DOCPARTMETAINFO*, VERSIONID?)>
 <!ELEMENT DOCPARTMETAINFO (IDENTIFIER?, TYPE?, ATTRIBUTE*, DOCPART?)?>
 <!ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE (VALUE+)>
 <!ATTLIST ATTRIBUTE ID CDATA #REQUIRED>
 <!ATTLIST ATTRIBUTE IGNORE (TRUE|FALSE) "FALSE">
 <!ATTLIST ATTRIBUTE OPERATOR (EQ|NE|LT|LE|GT|GE|BW|LIKE|IN) "EQ">
 <!ELEMENT VALUE (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT IDENTIFIER (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT TYPE (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT DOCPART (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT VERSIONID (#PCDATA)>
```

**Sample XML:**

```
  <CMSERVICESMSG>
<GBLMSGHDR>
    <HDRINFO>
        <HDRVERSNBRID/>
    </HDRINFO>
    <MSGATTRIB>
        <MSGID/>
        <MSGREQ/>
        <MSGTYPE/>
        <RESPREQIND/>
    </MSGATTRIB>
</GBLMSGHDR>
<SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <AUTHENTICATION>
        <USERID>XYZ</USERID>
        <USERPASS/>
    </AUTHENTICATION>
</SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
<PRESDOCMSGREQ>
    <ARCHIVEITEM/>
    <FUNCTION>FIND</FUNCTION>
    <DOCINFO>
        <GBLMETAINFO>
            <ATTRIBUTE ID="datetime" OPERATOR="EQ">
                <VALUE>20200702000000</VALUE>
                <VALUE>20200712000000</VALUE>
            </ATTRIBUTE>
            <CHILDCOMPONENT ID="Customers">
                <ATTRIBUTE ID="CustomerId">
                    <VALUE>123456789</VALUE>
                </ATTRIBUTE>
            </CHILDCOMPONENT>
            <DOCMETAINFO>
                <DOCPARTMETAINFO>
                    <DOCPART/>
                </DOCPARTMETAINFO>
            </DOCMETAINFO>
        </GBLMETAINFO>
    </DOCINFO>
 </PRESDOCMSGREQ>
 </CMSERVICESMSG>
```

**Exception:**

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Comment: You have invalid XML: `<DOCINFOS>...</DOCINFO>`. That may be causing this problem. You can check by using an online validator - for example, [this one](https://www.xmlvalidation.com).

Comment: sorry. its typo mistake. still error is same